# Запустить Open Cover UI

Tags: тестирование, плагин, visual-studio-2015

Доброго времени суток. Скачал [OpenCoverUI](https://github.com/OpenCoverUI/OpenCover.UI)

При запуске проекта на VS2015 вылезла ошибка

> Проект, создающий библиотеку классов, не может быть непосредственно запущен.
>   Для отладки данного проекта добавьте к решению проект, создающий приложение и ссылающийся на эту библиотеку, и сделайте его запускаемым.

Это я ещё запускал от имени администратора. 
До этого была ошибка

> Не удаётся начать отладку, так как отсутствует объект отладки "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe". Перестройте проект и попробуйте ещё раз, или установите свойства OutputPath и AssemblyName так, чтобы они указывали на правильное расположение целевой сборки.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить решение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите текст ошибки в теле вопроса текстом.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь указал.